# Why is my Google Analytics saying "Tracking Not Installed" when everything looks fine?

Tags: php, html, plugins, google-analytics

I'm using the Google Analytics by Yoast plugin and I Re-authenticate with my Google account, and it worked the UA address is correct and everything. From what I see in the `<head>` of my site http://boasish.com I can see `<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try using the chrome Google Analytics Debug extension - I gave up loading your page at 20MB!

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed the GA tracker, then you will need to wait at least 48 hours for data to start showing up in your standard reports (and for the error message to clear). You can check, in the meantime, with your Real-Time reports to see if you see your simultaneous visits. If you see data in RT reports, then likely you just need to wait. I can see hits going to your GA account, so things should be OK.